# Need help centering text output

Tags: java, text, center, output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class diamond {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        int lines = scan.nextInt();

        for(int counter = 1; counter <= lines; counter++)
        {   
            if (counter%2 != 0)
            {
                for(int count2 = 1; count2 <= counter; count2++){
                System.out.print("*");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am supposed to ask the user for a number of lines and output a diamond made of asterisks that number of lines tall.  I need some help figuring out how to center the asterisks.  I know for strings there is some String.utils method or something, but the output comes in pieces based on a for loop, so I don't think that really works here.  If it does, by all means let me know though.

Comment: You will need to calculate where to print spaces (`" "`) and where asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print a certain amount of spaces before each line. Then, you would need another for loop for the opposite. 
Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer ");
    int lines = scan.nextInt();

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= lines; counter++) {

        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines - (counter / 2) - 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int count2 = 1; count2 <= counter; count2++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    for (int counter = lines - 1; counter >= 1; counter--) {

        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines - (counter / 2) - 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int count2 = 1; count2 <= counter; count2++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should prepare a string to print out on each line, then you will know exactly how many characters it has, when the line increases, remove the two '*' in center of the string and add one " " in front of it, then print it out again.